# Looking for a Harry Potter Fanfiction where Harry cleans things when he is stressed

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I read a fan fiction in which Harry Potter cleans things when he is stressed. From what I remember, it's second or third year and Snape finds Harry cleaning an abandoned classroom or cupboard. Snape then ends up helping Harry by letting him clean things in the potions classroom or something.
That's all I can remember about it, sorry it's not a lot to go on.

Comment: Do you remember on what site you read it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe "An Unconventional Relationship" by TCRegan  & Sophie Richards?
https://xa.yimg.com/kq/groups/.../An+Unconventional+Relationship+-+TCRegan.pdf

Growing up with the Dursleys left Harry with some unusual quirks, for example, he finds cleaning soothing, and sometimes he misses his cupboard.  Although it takes Snape awhile to stop suspecting Harry of sucking up because he stays after class to clean up the lab, Snape eventually realizes cleaning is a stress management technique for Harry, and the hostility between them eases.  Over time, Snape, as he becomes more aware of the reasons for Harry's quirks, goes out of his way to provide a sense of security and stability for Harry as an emotional connection is made.

I don't remember if there is a physical aspect to their relationship, but I'm pretty sure the story is considered Snarry.